# Perl issues while sending emojis over socket

Tags: json, perl, sockets, unicode, apple-push-notifications

My Perl script sends push notifications to an Apple APNS server. It works except when I try to send emojis (special characters).

#### My code

```
use DBI;
use JSON;
use Net::APNS::Persistent;
use Data::Dumper;
use Encode;

my $cfg;
my $apns;

...;

sub connect {
    my ($sandbox, $cert, $key, $pass) = $cfg->getAPNSServer();

    $apns = Net::APNS::Persistent->new({
        sandbox => $sandbox,
        cert    => $cert,
        key     => $key,
    }) or die("[-] Unable to connect to APNS server");

}

sub push {
    my $msg = $_[1];

    Logger::log(5, "[APNS Client] Got message ".Dumper($msg));

    #Encode::_utf8_off($msg);
    utf8::encode($msg);

    my $pack = decode_json($msg);
    my ($token, $payload) = @{$pack};

    Logger::log(5, "Sending push with token: $token and Data: \n".Dumper($payload));

    $apns->queue_notification(
       $token,
       $payload
       );
    $apns->send_queue;
}
```

So in the push subroutine I pass JSON data with the format given below. My problem is with the emoji character `\x{2460}`. You can see I added this line

```
utf8::encode($msg);
```

Before decoding the data. If I remove this line I get an error while decoding the JSON data

```
 Wide character in subroutine entry at .....
```

With the above line added I can decode my JSON data. However when I try to write to the socket in the next line (`$apns->send_queue`) gives

```
Cannot decode string with wide characters at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/Encode.pm line 176
```

How do I solve this?

#### Message format (JSON)

```
["token",
    { 
      "aps":{
          "alert":"Alert: \x{2460}",
          "content-available":1,
          "badge":2,
          "sound":"default.aiff"
       },
       "d":"Meta"
   }
]
```

**Dumper Output**

```
[-] [ 2015-08-25T20:03:15 ] [APNS Client] Got message $VAR1 = "[\"19c360f37681035730a26cckjgkjgkj58b2d20326986f4265ee802c103f51\",{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Alert: \x{24bc}\",\"content-available\":1,\"badge\":2,\"sound\":\"default.aiff\"},\"d\":\"Meta\"}]";

[-] [ 2015-08-25T20:03:15 ] Sending push with token: 119c360f37681035730a26cckjgkjgkj58b2d20326986f4265ee802c103f51 and Data:
$VAR1 = {
          'aps' => {
                     'alert' => "Alert: \x{24bc}",
                     'content-available' => 1,
                     'badge' => 2,
                     'sound' => 'default.aiff'
                   },
          'd' => 'Meta'
        };

[x] [ 2015-08-25T20:03:15 ] [APNS Client] Error writing to socket. Reconnecting : Cannot decode string with wide characters at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/Encode.pm line 176.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `decode_json` expects JSON encoded using UTF-8, so if you're starting with "decoded" JSON, it is proper to encode it as you did.

```
utf8::encode( my $json_utf8 = $json_uni );
my $data = decode_json($json_utf8);
```

However, it would have been simpler to use `from_json`.

```
my $data = from_json($json_uni);
```

---

Now on to your question. Whoever wrote Net::APNS::Persistent messed up big time. I looked at the source code, and they expect the alert message to be encoded using UTF-8. Adding the following will make your structure conform with the module's wonky expectation:

```
utf8::encode(
   ref($payload->{aps}{alert}) eq 'HASH'
      ? $payload->{aps}{alert}{body}
      : $payload->{aps}{alert}
);
```

It wouldn't surprise me if you ran into other issues. Notably, the modules uses the *bytes* module, a sure sign that something is being done incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ikegami. Unfortunately thats the only perl apns module I found.

Comment: This is essentially what nwellnhof posted. I was just called away in the middle of composing mine. Note that my solution fixes the problem for all valid inputs, unlike his.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to UTF-8 encode the alert in `$payload` before sending it. You can also use [`from_json`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#from_json) instead of `decode_json` to avoid the first encoding step:

```
sub push {
    my $msg = $_[1];

    Logger::log(5, "[APNS Client] Got message ".Dumper($msg));

    my $pack = from_json($msg);
    my ($token, $payload) = @{$pack};

    Logger::log(5, "Sending push with token: $token and Data: \n".Dumper($payload));

    # UTF-8 encode before sending.
    utf8::encode($payload->{aps}{alert});

    $apns->queue_notification(
       $token,
       $payload
       );
    $apns->send_queue;
}
```

Comment: I never used from_json before; but i guess it didnt decode my json the way it did before; Im getting a hash while dumping my $payload.  Sending push with token: 19c360f37681035730a26ccbdd54d50aa258b2d20326986f4265ee802c103f51 and Data:
$VAR1 = 'HASH(0x9471ed8)';
However, utf8::encode($payload->{aps}{alert}); works. So, Im doing utf8::encode twice. It works this way but a bit wired.

Comment: @user3360140 Did you notice the edit I made to my answer?